# CSS - removing space under the html tag - responsive issue

Tags: css

http://primoburgers.herokuapp.com/

I am working on this website. It looks fine on my laptop, but when I load it onto a bigger desktop monitor, it has a red bar under the html tag at the bottom of the page. This red bar shows under all of the pages. Does anyone know how to remove this?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Please edit some relevant code and some details about what you tested so we can take a look. Thanks !

Comment: @G.EGCB opening the site and using the browsers inspector takes care of this

Comment: What an observation @user2174484. Posting a question on SO should show at least some details and research so other users can easily follows and maybe solve their own problems. But still, thanks for your constructive comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your html and body elements to height: 100% first.

After that set top-pic-wrapper to height: 85% or so. % height wont take effect till the other parent elements also have a height set for them.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define a height for your menu pic class.

Just change your class below

```
.heightMenuPic {
   height: auto;
}
```